# Installation package generator for Postgres, Tomcat, Java (jre) and a war file

Tags: windows, java, postgresql, apache, installer

My aim is to build a silent installer to install the following components on a user machine.

Postgres including PgAdmin,
Apache Tomcat 7
Java (JRE) 7.0
And a war file

I am targeting Windows only, Windows 7 and above.

What software do you recommend to bundle all the software and do a clean, silent install? I am currently reviewing Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS), but found the scripting not easy to understand.